# Eclipse Secure Password Storage and ssh-agent

Tags: eclipse, ssh, ssh-keys

Is it possible that Eclipse Secure Password Storage can use my ssh-agent to avoid the Secure Password Storage prompt (on Linux)?
-Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Eclipse Secure Password Storage manages passwords while ssh-agent manages private keys.